# Why am I unable to access this global variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable inside of a for loop that can't be accessed outside even though I've made it global. Why am I unable to access it? the variable is "finalVar" Here's the code:

```
  $(function(){
    var successfullStatements = $("#successfullStatements"),
        errors = $("#errors")

    html5sql.process(
         [{
             sql:"SELECT * FROM StarWarsCharacters WHERE name=?;",
             data:[Jsonvar]
         }],
         function(transaction, results, rowsArray){
             for(var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++){
                //the variable I tried to make global
                 window.finalVar = rowsArray[i].name;

             }

         },
         function(error, statement){

         }
    );
  });
  });

  alert(finalVar); //tried checking to see if variable could be accessed
```

Comment: I bet there's an asynchronous function which you think is synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

`html5sql.process` is an asynchronous function. So, the `finalVar` will not be populated unless the function pass to `html5sql.process` is executed. But that will get executed only when `results` are fetched. So, you may have to move the `alert` to the place where the `result` is getting really populated.

```
$(function() {
    var successfullStatements = $("#successfullStatements"),
        errors = $("#errors")
        html5sql.process(
            [{
                sql: "SELECT * FROM StarWarsCharacters WHERE name=?;",
                data: [Jsonvar]
            }],
            function(transaction, results, rowsArray) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++) {
                    //the variable I tried to make global
                    alert(rowsArray[i].name);
                }
            },
            function(error, statement) {}
        );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   try this:

   html5sql.process(
     [{
         sql:"SELECT * FROM StarWarsCharacters WHERE name=?;",
         data:[Jsonvar],
         async:false
     }],
     function(transaction, results, rowsArray){
         for(var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++){
            //the variable I tried to make global
             window.finalVar = rowsArray[i].name;

         }

     },
     function(error, statement){

     }
);

Please note the function is called asynchronously here.so you have to make the function call synchronous by making "async:false". Then you can get the variable's value outside the for loop.
```

Comment: And even if this was based in `jQuery`, please don't recommend setting `async` to `false`.  We'd be better off if nobody knew that option existed.